# opengl gbuffer use GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE texture issues

Tags: opengl

i first render scene into gbuffer(position,normal,*color*),but in deferred render pass the *color* texture was jittering all the time, so i want to change the *color* texture to GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,like below, but it failed, why?

```
enum _GL_GBUFFER_TEXTURE_TYPE_ { _position_, _normal_, _albedo_spec_,_texture_cnt_ };
bool initialize(int2 dim){
        dim2 = dim;

        //gbuffer
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &gBuffer);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gBuffer);

        //position texture
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + _position_, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                             textures[_position_].create2d(dim2, GL_RGBA32F/*GL_RGB16F*/, GL_RGBA/*GL_RGB*/, GL_FLOAT, NULL), 0);
        //normal texture
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + _normal_, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                              textures[_normal_].create2d(dim2, GL_RGBA32F/*GL_RGB16F*/, GL_RGBA/*GL_RGB*/, GL_FLOAT, NULL), 0);
        //color texture
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + _albedo_spec_, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,
                                              textures[_albedo_spec_].create2d_msaa(dim2,GL_RGBA8,8), 0);
                                              //textures[_albedo_spec_].create2d(dim2,GL_RGBA,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,NULL),0);

        //tell OpenGL which color attachments we'll use (of this framebuffer) for rendering 
        GLuint attachments[_texture_cnt_]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < _texture_cnt_; i++) attachments[i] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i;
        glDrawBuffers(_texture_cnt_, attachments);

        //create and attach depth buffer (renderbuffer)
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboDepth);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, dim2.x, dim2.y);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);

        //finally check if framebuffer is complete
        if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
            std::cout << "[GBuffer] : Framebuffer not complete!" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: apart from the invalid use of GL as pointed out in the answer, there is a more fundamental problem: Deferred shading and multisampling don't go well together. Doing the multisample resolve before the shading pass will result in attributes of different objects being mixed together, instead of the final colors of the object. Working with the unresolved per-sample data directly basically turns multisampling into supersampling and negates the advantage of multisampling alltogether.

Comment: oh,i see! but how can i resolve the problem that texture-color jittering/pulsing when camera is moving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your framebuffer is not complete, because (see [Khronos reference page - `glCheckFramebufferStatus`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xhtml)):

> `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE` is returned if the value of `GL_RENDERBUFFER_SAMPLES` is not the same for all attached renderbuffers; if the value of `GL_TEXTURE_SAMPLES` is the not same for all attached textures; or, if the attached images are a mix of renderbuffers and textures, the value of `GL_RENDERBUFFER_SAMPLES` does not match the value of `GL_TEXTURE_SAMPLES`.

This means, all of the textures, that you attach to the frame buffer have to be multisample textures.

Comment: thanks for help! after i change all the textures to multisample-texture, however, the texture jittering artifacts still exists when camera is moving, how can i fix this problem?

Comment: ^0^, i tried to create a new problem but somehow it says my question description didnt meet the requirements. so i simply paste a link [here](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1nuQ6KL7) from which can see the right-wall-texture jittering/pulsing when camera moving. thanks for help!

Comment: @redips Did you fix the jittering problem? I have the same when I set the multi-sample texture to GL_RGB16F